# How to rename a string in all file types in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a folder that contains all file types for example:

```
10November2017.txt
01October1986.txt
20September2000.dat
13February1992.txt
```

I am running the following 2 tasks using PowerShell:

1. Search all files with .txt extension then
2. Rename all of the returned .txt files in a format "yyyyMMdd.txt" for example:

   - 20171110.txt
   - 19861001.txt
   - 19920113.txt

I am able to get through task 1 but a bit struggled with task 2. 
Could you please kindly assist ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: will the script generate the "yyyMMdd" using the previous file name?

Comment: Parse the basename of the file to a date, then re-format that date and rename the file accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one liner:

```
gci -File *.txt|where BaseName -match '^(\d{2})(\w{3,9})(\d{4})$'|Ren -NewName {$matches[3]+([DateTime]::ParseExact($matches[2],"MMMM",$CIUS).Month.ToString('00'))+$matches[1]+$_.Extension} -Whatif
```

If the output looks OK remove the trailing `-whatif`

If your locale settings don't fit the month names to match you can't use `$null` with ParseExact but have to define a different culture  variable :

```
$CIUS = New-Object system.globalization.cultureinfo("en-US")
```

and replace `$null` with that variable.

The longer variant

```
$CIUS = New-Object system.globalization.cultureinfo("en-US")
Get-ChildItem -File *.txt|
  Where-Object BaseName -match '^(\d{2})(\w{3,9})(\d{4})$'|
    Rename-Item -NewName {$matches[3]+`
        ([DateTime]::ParseExact($matches[2],"MMMM",$CIUS).Month.ToString('00'))+`
        $matches[1]+`
        $_.Extension"} -Whatif
```

With explanations

- The -match RegEx anchors at begin `^`and end `$` and builds three groups from day, month name and year.
- the script block in Rename receives the groups aka `$matches` in reverse order
- using ParseExact to replace the month name with it's ordinal number.

---

If you ever have the need to reverse this (with a different locale) for example the french name for august:

```
PS> $CIFR = New-Object system.globalization.cultureinfo("fr-FR")
PS> $CIFR.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames[8 -1]
août
```

To get a list of `cultureinfo` items:

```
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures([System.Globalization.CultureTypes]::AllCultures)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`DateTime.ParseExact()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse the date based on the `BaseName` property (the filename without extension), then convert it back to a string in the desired format.

The full name of the month is designated using the `MMMM` specifier

```
$txtFiles = Get-ChildItem .\path\to\files -Filter *.txt
foreach($file in $txtFiles){
    try{
        $fileDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($file.BaseName,'ddMMMMyyyy',$null)
        $file |Rename-Item -NewName ('{0:yyyyMMdd}{1}' -f $fileDate,$file.Extension)
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "File base name $($file.BaseName) not recognized as valid date"
    }
}
```

Comment: i mean that makes logic but i think you need to create a array or a vector or whatever first, with the name of the months and then  you compare the first 2 characters of the .txt file (the priginal) to the same position in the months array -1 and use that to assemble a new string, some the original file looks like this : 01October1999.txt and the output file will look like this 01091999.txt (and then just assemble it to look like this format yyyyMMdd), at least thats what i think the OP wants.

Comment: @jeyejow Why? If his sample file names are representative and match the system locale, the input format is clearly `ddMMMMyyyy` - why would you attempt to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Because the output of your code will be , if the input for example is 01October1999.txt, it will be 1999October01.txt, and if you see the OP desired output, it must be, in this example, 19991001.txt , so you must have a library (in this case an array of something related) holding the text of the name of the months so you can convert them to numbers

Comment: @jeyejow Have you tried to run the code? In `Rename-Item` I use the format string `yyyyMMdd` - resulting in `19991001` for your example

Comment: oh, so it does alreaddy that internally? i didnt realise that, my bad :-)

Comment: @jeyejow That's the entire point of `ParseExact()` :-) you get an actual `DateTime` instance

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, you're awesome. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another one-liner solution, maybe a bit shorter:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match "\D"} | Rename-Item -NewName {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Basename, "ddMMMMyyyy", $null).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + $_.extension}
```

Description:

`-Filter "*.txt"` filters only text files

`-Recurse | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match "\D"}` iterates only through objects that contain non-digit characters in order to filter out the newly renames items

`[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Basename, "ddMMMMyyyy", $null)` converts the file name (no extension) to a date object

`.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + $_.extension` converts the date object to the desired string representation and append the extension

Comment: Great! Thanks guys